# Switch statement on page load in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, switch-statement

I have this switch statement that looks for certain classes on the page on page load and need to rewrite into one of my controllers.

Any ideas on how to rewrite this simple task in Angular?

```js
$('.radior').each(function() {
  var ones = $(this).find('.newone'); // newone's of current .radior
  var count = ones.length;

  switch (count) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        var sub = ['full', 'half', 'third'];
     ones.addClass( sub[count - 1] + " col-xs-12 col-md-" + (12 / count));
        break;
      
      case 4:
        ones.addClass( "quarter col-xs-12" );
        break;

      case 4:
        ones.addClass( "another col-xs-12" );
        break;
  }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform that in a directive:

```
angular.directive('radior', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var ones = element.find('.newone'); // newone's of current .radior
            var count = ones.length;

            switch (count) {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    var sub = ['full', 'half', 'third'];
                    ones.addClass(sub[count - 1] + " col-xs-12 col-md-" + (12 / count));
                    break;

                case 4:
                    ones.addClass("quarter col-xs-12");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    ones.addClass("another col-xs-12");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Now in your HTML you will have something like this:

```
<radior>
   <div class="newone">test</div>
</radior>
```

I didn't test it but it should work or it needs small fixes for your particular needs.

Comment: Looks amazing, I will test out this puppy now. Many thanks